# How to change the Radius of an Already created Geofence without getting same IDs multiple times

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence

`Scenerio` : I have created a Geofence with `ID=1` with say `Radius=500` now i update the same Geofence with `ID=1` to `Radius=1000`.

`What I did` : I re-registered the same Geofence ID and I get a message as `Success GeofenceRequestIds=[1, 1]` (two similar ids) .

Now as i keepon modifying the Radius the message keeps on increasing the array of ids for eg. after 4 changes i get `Success GeofenceRequestIds=[1, 1, 1, 1]`

`Question:` Does this mean that I would get all these IDs when I receive the transition (Breaching of geofence) of my GeoFence `ID:1`.

`Alternate query`:Should i remove the Geofence Id first before changing the Radius and then again add it on the same location with changed radius, can it make a difference.

Suggestion on this would be great.

Comment: what do you mean by "I get a message as Success GeofenceRequestIds=[1, 1]"?

Comment: It means the same `ID's` have been registered for Geofence location listening with the Google play services successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is [HERE](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingClient#public-taskvoid-addgeofences-geofencingrequest-geofencingrequest,-pendingintent-pendingintent):

> If an existing geofence with the same request ID is already registered, the old geofence is replaced by the new one, and the new
> pendingIntent is used to generate intents for alerts.

Comment: great, thanks for the inputs, i believe the Success message would be independent of the pending intent, and wouldn't be called multiple times

Comment: @Anuj BE ADVISED: at the top of that documentation is warning "This class is deprecated. Use LocationServices."

Comment: When did this happen, it was barely a new API